# Emacs, removing all lines that don't match?

Tags: regex, emacs

I use the `(query-replace-regexp "from" "to")` expression regularly when making large changes in a text file.

I'd like a regular expression, if one exists, for removing all lines that *don't* match. For example, in a RedHat SPEC file for building a RPM I want to leave *just* the lines that begin with `/^Patch/` in them (and delete all non-matching lines). Easy enough with `grep -E '^Patch'` but is there a way in Emacs?

I tried:

```
(query-replace-regexp "^\\(?!Patch\\)[^\r\n]*$" "")
```

to no avail (negative-lookahead appears unsupported).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try <kbd>M-x keep-lines ^Patch</kbd> instead:

> `(keep-lines REGEXP &optional RSTART REND INTERACTIVE)`
>
> Delete all lines except those containing matches for REGEXP.

There is also the opposite command, <kbd>M-x flush-lines</kbd>, which removes lines matching a regexp.

Answer (score 25):

use `M-x delete-non-matching-lines` and `M-x delete-matching-lines`

Comment: The documentation for `delete-non-matching-lines` explains this is an alias for `keep-lines` and `delete-matching-lines` is an alias for `flush-lines`.

Answer (score 5):

If it's just "Patch" you are looking for, you can identify lines not matching `^Patch` by using

```
^([^P]|P[^a]|Pa[^t]|Pat[^c]|Patc[^h])[^\r\n]*$
```

I admit, it is rather ugly, though. =)